# How to prove this identity of ceiling function?

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My book writes down this identity of least integer function:

$$\lceil x\rceil +\left\lceil x + \frac{1}{n}\right \rceil + \left\lceil x + \frac{2}{n}\right \rceil + \cdots +\left\lceil x + \frac{n -1}{n}\right \rceil = \lceil nx\rceil + n-1 $$.

It didn't deduce it, however. I googled a bit about ceiling function but couldn't find any deduction. It is more like Hermite's Identity of floor function. Can anyone show me how to deduce this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like $ \lceil nx\rceil + n-1$ instead of $\lceil x\rceil + n-1$ ?  The formula seems false for $n=3$ and $x=10000$

Comment: @GBQT: I don't know, sir; I really copied what my book wrote; maybe the book mistook:(

Comment: Note that the left side is about $nx$, while the right is about $x$, so it cannot be right

Comment: @Ross Millikan: Sir, can you refer me any site that deduces it? BTW, is there any special name for this like "Hermite's Identity" for floor functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way of doing it is $$f(x)=\lceil x\rceil+\left\lceil x+\frac1n\right\rceil+\dots +\left\lceil x+1-\frac1n\right\rceil  - \left\lceil nx\right\rceil$$

We have $$
\begin{align}
f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)=&\left\lceil x+\frac1n\right\rceil+\left\lceil x+\frac2n\right\rceil+\dots +\left\lceil x+1\right\rceil  - \left\lceil nx+1\right\rceil \\
=&\left\lceil x+\frac{1}{n}\right\rceil+\left\lceil x+\frac2n\right\rceil+\dots +\left\lceil x\right\rceil  - \left\lceil nx\right\rceil \\
=&\lceil x\rceil+\left\lceil x+\frac1n\right\rceil+\dots +\left\lceil x+1-\frac{1}{n}\right\rceil  - \left\lceil nx\right\rceil\\
=&f(x)
\end{align}$$

So $f$ is $\frac1n$-periodic. And we only need to evaluate it over $\left(0,\frac1n\right]$, in which case

$$f(x) = n-1$$

This is because if $x\in(0,\frac{1}{n}]$, then $x,x+\frac{1}{n},\dots,x+\frac{n-1}{n}$ and $nx\in(0,1]$ and $$\left\lceil x\right\rceil = \left\lceil x+\frac{1}{n}\right\rceil=\dots=\left\lceil x+\frac{n-1}{n}\right\rceil=\left\lceil nx\right\rceil=1$$

Comment: Nice approach! But shouldn't you have $\lceil nx+1\rceil$ when you evaluate $f(x+1/n)$? I think that would change the picture here...

Comment: I think the lest term of $f\left(x+\frac1n\right)$ has a typo.

Comment: @bartgol: You came first by ~3 sec!!

Comment: @bartgol Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: There you go. Elegant solution by the way!

Comment: @bartgol, It's true that $f(1/n)=n$ (since the function is periodic), but it's convenient to have all the values be in $(0,1]$, since the ceiling function is constant (equal to $1$) over it.

Comment: +1; I could comprehend the deduction of how it was periodic; but I couldn't understand the last line:"And we only need to evaluate it over $(0,{1\over n}]$,". Cn you please explain this?

Comment: @user36790 Basically, if a function has a period $T$, then studying it over $[0,T)$ (or $(0,T]$, $[a,a+T)$, etc.) is enough to calculate it over all of $\Bbb R$. $$ $$
In this case, we have $T=1/n$ and we know that if $x\in (0,T]$, then $f(x)$ is equal to $n-1$. So if $x\in (T,2T]$, then $f(x) = f(x-T) = n-1$. If $x\in (2T,3T]$, then $f(x)=f(x-2T)=n-1$ and so on. So we know that $f(x) = n-1$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$. The same thing can be done for $(\infty,0]$

Comment: @If you don't mind, sir, may I request you to please tell why you've written $f(x) = n-1$ ; sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @user36790 Well, since $x\in(0,\frac1n]$, then $x,x+\frac1n,\dots,x+1-\frac1n$ and $nx$ are all in $(0,1]$, so their $\lceil\ \rceil$ is equal to $1$. So we get $f(x)=(1+1+\dots+1) -1=n-1$

Comment: Thanks, sir; just one suggestion- can you write the argument above in your answer?? It would look perfectly complete, at-least for me:)

Comment: @user36790 Sure, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Using the general property $\lceil u+m\rceil=\lceil u\rceil+m$ if $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can rewrite the proposed identity as

$$\lceil x\rceil+\left\lceil x+{1\over n}-1\right\rceil+\left\lceil x+{2\over n}-1\right\rceil+\cdots+\left \lceil x+{n-1\over n}-1 \right\rceil=\lceil nx\rceil$$

which, on simplifying and reordering, becomes

$$\lceil x\rceil+\left\lceil x-{1\over n}\right\rceil+\left\lceil x-{2\over n}\right \rceil+\cdots+\left\lceil x-{n-1\over n}\right \rceil=\lceil nx\rceil$$

The same general property allows us to assume that $0\lt x\le1$, i.e., $(k-1)/n\lt x\le k/n$ for some $1\le k\le n$.  It's now easy to see that the first $k$ terms on the left hand side of the proposed identity are equal to $1$ and the rest are $0$, while $k-1\lt nx\le k$ implies $\lceil nx\rceil=k$, and thus the two sides are indeed equal.

Comment: Sir, firstly, thanks for answering but can you please elaborate how you wrote ${(k-1) \over n}\lt x\le {k\over n}$? Also, can you please explain the line "The same general property allows us to assume that $0<x≤1$"? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: @user36790, there are $n$ terms on the left hand side, so if $x$ is shifted by an integer amount $m$, that side shifts by $nm$, while on the right hand side, $\lceil n(x+m)\rceil=\lceil nx+nm\rceil]=\lceil nx\rceil+nm$.  Once you have $x$ between $0$ and $1$, you know it lies between some pair of consecutive multiples of the fraction $1/n$, with the upper multiple at most $n/n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* This answer provides a *combinatorial approach*. First we derive a nice formula which is interesting by itself. Then we show that OP's claim is an easy generalisation of it. All of the referred identities can be found at the Wiki page of *[floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)*.

> Let's assume we have $p$ objects and we want to distribute these objects evenly on $n$ heaps. The size of a heap is determined by
>   \begin{align*}
> p=qn+r\qquad\qquad0\leq r < n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   If $r$ is zero then each heap has size $q=\left\lfloor \frac{p}{n}\right\rfloor$.  If the remainder $r$ is greater than zero we have to distribute the $r$ objects evenly on the $n$ heaps, so that $r$ heaps will have size $q+1=\left\lceil\frac{p}{n}\right\rceil$ while $n-r$ heaps will have size $q=\left\lfloor \frac{p}{n}\right\rfloor$.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> p=\left\lfloor\frac{p}{n}\right\rfloor(n-r)+\left\lceil\frac{p}{n}\right\rceil r
> \end{align*}
>
> Now we want to address each single heap. Considering the $k$-th heap with $1\leq k \leq n$ we want an expression which gives $1$ in $r$ cases and $0$ in the remaining $n-r$ cases. This can be obtained with
>   \begin{align*}
> \left\lceil\frac{r-k+1}{n}\right\rceil=[k\leq r]
> \end{align*}
>   Here we use the *[Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* giving one if $k\leq r$ and zero otherwise. Now we can write $p$ as sum of $n$ heaps by iterating $k$ from $1$ to $n$ with a heap heaving either $q=\left\lfloor \frac{p}{n}\right\rfloor$ elements or $q+1$ elements.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> p&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(q+\left\lceil\frac{r-k+1}{n}\right\rceil\right)\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\left\lceil q +\frac{r-k+1}{n}\right\rceil\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\left\lceil \frac{p-k+1}{n}\right\rceil\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\left\lceil \frac{p-k}{n}\right\rceil\right)\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment:

- In (2) we use for integers $q$ and real $x$ the identity $\lceil q+x \rceil=\lceil q \rceil+x$
- In (3) we use the relationship $p=qn+r$
- In (4) we shift the index by one

> Leaving the combinatorial interpretation we can extend the validity of $p$ in (4) to zero and negative values, since the representation (1) is also valid for $p\in \mathbb{Z}$. We get the nice identity
>
> \begin{align*}
> p=\left\lceil \frac{p}{n}\right\rceil+\left\lceil \frac{p-1}{n}\right\rceil
> +\cdots+\left\lceil \frac{p-n+1}{n}\right\rceil\qquad\qquad p\in\mathbb{Z}, n\geq 1
> \end{align*}

With this formula at hand it's only a small step to proof OPs claim.

> Exchanging in (4) the order of summation  by replacing $k$ with $n-1-k$ we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> p=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\left\lceil \frac{p-n+1+k}{n}\right\rceil\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $p$ can be *any* integer we can set $p=\left\lceil nx\right\rceil+n-1$ with $x$ being real and get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left\lceil nx\right\rceil+n-1&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lceil \frac{\left\lceil nx\right\rceil+k}{n}\right\rceil\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\left\lceil x+ \frac{k}{n}\right\rceil\right)\\
> \end{align*}
>
> which shows OP's claim is valid.

*Comment:*

- In (5) we use the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lceil \frac{\left\lceil y\right\rceil+k}{n}\right\rceil=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lceil \frac {y+k}{n}\right\rceil$ for $y$ real, $k,n$ integer, $n$ positive.

**Note:** This example can be found besides many more interesting applications of floor and ceiling functions in  [Concrete Mathematics](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf) by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lfloor -x \rfloor = - \lceil x \rceil$, substituting $x\to -x$ in the Hermite's Floor Function Identity, one obtains
\begin{align*} -\lceil nx \rceil = \lfloor n(-x) \rfloor &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left \lfloor -\left(x-\frac{k}{n}\right) \right \rfloor = -\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left \lceil x-\frac{k}{n} \right \rceil \\ \lceil nx \rceil &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left \lceil x-\frac{k}{n} \right \rceil   \end{align*} which is precisely the Hermite's Ceiling Function Identity

Rearranging the index by substitution $k\to n-k$
\begin{align*} \lceil nx \rceil &= \sum_{k=1}^n \left \lceil x-\frac{n-k}{n} \right \rceil \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \left \lceil x+\frac{k}{n} \right \rceil-1 \right) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left \lceil x+\frac{k}{n} \right \rceil \: + \lceil x+1 \rceil - \lceil x \rceil -n \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left \lceil x+\frac{k}{n} \right \rceil \; -n+1 \\ \lceil nx \rceil +n-1 &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left \lceil x+\frac{k}{n} \right \rceil \end{align*}